# how to custom chart in primefaces

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

in primefaces 6.0, i want to custom chart throught *Extender* (https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf page 93)
code below:

```
<p:chart type="line" model="#{chartViewLine.lineModel1}"/>
```

and Bean, i set:

```
private LineChartModel lineModel1;
...
lineModel1 = initLinearModel();
lineModel1.setExtender("extender"); //this wil custom with js
```

and Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 //<![CDATA[
 function extender() {
     this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
         pointLabels: {show: false}
     };
 }

//]]>
</script>
```

but, nothing happened. i'm tried

```
<p:chart type="line" model="#{chartViewLine.lineModel1}" widgetVar="test1"/>
function extender() {
 this = PF('test1');
 this.cfg.seriesDefaults = {
     pointLabels: {show: false}
 };
```

}
but still like that, please help me, how to custom it!

Comment: Primefaces does not use chart.js, it uses jqplot. And 'nothing happened' and 'still like that' is not clear... Please elaborate and what did you debug?

Comment: @Kukeltje i'm using jqplot with option seriesDefaults. i want custom it.
in here, LineChartModel  draw line with point labels (link: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/line.xhtml),  but i don't want show points same this (link: http://www.jqplot.com/examples/point-labels.php)

Comment: I'm not asking what you want, I'm asking what you debugged. Is the extender function called at all? Does the console show errors lots of things **you** can and **should** do... (including correcting the tagging of the question)

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/gchart.jsf